# Transferred 0 file(s) while transferring war file from Jenkins server to remote server

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, ssh

There's a jenkins server where my jenkinswar.war file is present in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project2/target/jenkinswar.war`

I want this file to be transferred to other remote server at `/opt/docker` location.

So I have configured as below:

[image]

Even though the build is successful, still the files transferred are 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an archive stage before this, maybe it isn't picking it because the war file isn't present when it needs to copy...
you can also try using '*/target/**/jenkinswar.war' for your source file